Software Rendering text glitch in DearImGUI, fixes?

the text looks like blocks, but neither of the fonts are supposed to look that way, and I don't know why it looks wrong, yet.
Main File:
#include <SDL_main.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <imgui.h>
#include <imgui_impl_sdl2.h>
#include <imgui_impl_sdlrenderer2.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create SDL window
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("ImGui SDL2 Software Renderer example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create SDL renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
    if (!renderer)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize ImGui
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

    // Initialize ImGui backends
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_InitForSDLRenderer(window, renderer);
    ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_Init(renderer);

    // Build font atlas
    io.Fonts->AddFontDefault();
    unsigned char* tex_pixels = NULL;
    int tex_width, tex_height;
    io.Fonts->GetTexDataAsRGBA32(&tex_pixels, &tex_width, &tex_height);

    // Main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                done = true;
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE && event.window.windowID == SDL_GetWindowID(window))
                done = true;
            ImGui_ImplSDL2_ProcessEvent(&event);
        }

        // Start ImGui frame
        ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        // Show ImGui demo window
        ImGui::ShowDemoWindow();

        // Render
        ImGui::Render();
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 114, 144, 154, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplSDL2_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}



Config file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
    <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
    <Project>
        <Option title="NiaAppDevTemplate" />
        <Option compiler="gcc" />
        <Option use_console_runner="0" />
        <Build>
            <Target title="Debug">
                <Option output="bin/Debug/NiaAppDevTemplate.exe" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Debug/" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-g" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add option="-lmingw32" />
                    <Add option="-lSDL2main" />
                    <Add option="-lSDL2" />
                    <Add option="-mwindows" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
            <Target title="Release">
                <Option output="bin/Release/NiaAppDevTemplate.exe" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
                <Option type="1" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Compiler>
                    <Add option="-O2" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                    <Add option="-s" />
                    <Add option="-lmingw32" />
                    <Add option="-lSDL2main" />
                    <Add option="-lSDL2" />
                    <Add option="-mwindows" />
                </Linker>
            </Target>
        </Build>
        <Compiler>
            <Add option="-Wall" />
            <Add option="-fexceptions" />
            <Add directory="Libraries/SDL2-2.30.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2" />
            <Add directory="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/backends" />
            <Add directory="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5" />
            <Add directory="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um" />
            <Add directory="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/shared" />
            <Add option="-Dmain=SDL_main" />
        </Compiler>
        <Linker>
            <Add option="-LLibraries/SDL2-2.30.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" />
            <Add library="SDL2" />
            <Add library="setupapi" />
            <Add library="ole32" />
            <Add library="imm32" />
            <Add library="user32" />
            <Add library="gdi32" />
            <Add library="winmm" />
            <Add library="dsound" />
            <Add library="kernel32" />
            <Add library="shell32" />
            <Add library="advapi32" />
            <Add library="version" />
        </Linker>
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/imgui.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/imgui_demo.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/imgui_draw.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/backends/imgui_impl_sdlrenderer2.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/backends/imgui_impl_sdl2.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/imgui_tables.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="Libraries/imgui-1.90.5/imgui_widgets.cpp" />
        <Unit filename="main.cpp" />
        <Extensions>
            <lib_finder disable_auto="1" />
        </Extensions>
    </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>


the purpose of the program is to help get a good boilerplate for widget and graphics, via software rendering, so that I can focus on the more abstract aspects of software design.

please reduce the amount of text in the quesiton. Papragraphs like eg this one "So it's nice to see everyone again. and if we could trouble shoot this together you'd be my fricken heroes thank you. Chat GPT says its a common issue, but then the conversation ended, and its advice about how to trouble shoot, seemed~ circular..." do not add anything useful to the quesiton and make it less accessible

this reads like a blog post about chatgpt rather than a focused questions about programming

tldr: isntead of the font being a font, it's just blocks of square~ness... and I have no clue why, or how to test if its me or not, so yeah... this is like a late night project that I'm doing when I'm half-asleep. so that helps me to think mathematically, but makes it kinda hard to proof-read, cos when you're tired your eyes can't focus. it could be something super obvious, like maybe we didn't type anything to display? I dunno. check for the obvious pls, I'm dumb. thank you.

hey "
463035818_is_not_an_ai" I just saw you. I shall. I'm a sloth gimme a tic thanks for the heads up. figuring out how to fix it

@–
463035818_is_not_an_ai
I just updated it. better?
If not, I suck at adhering to style guides apparently, but I don't you showing me how its done if you wanna edit it

ok, i helped you a bit. THough, now it became clear that there was no specific quesiton to begin with. What exactly is wrong with the code? How else should the output look?

ChatGPT isn't always forthright and misses obvious things, last night I was under the impression that it was running the test library, but I just checked my sourcecode and I don't see that. I'm gonna compile one more time just to do a sanity check. but if it isn't running a test program, why are so few lines producing such a complicated gui? also if it isn't part of a test program, then perhaps it just never thought it would need to tell the font to use actual characters? I dunno. confused. chatgpt will do that to you :(

if you cannot phrase your question without mentioning chatgpt, then most likely it is not an ontopic question. Frankly, I dont care about your experience with chatgpt. I would care about your issues with code.

the question is
463035818_is_not_an_ai, why is it blocks instead of lorem ipsum? because my coding tool (chatgpt) was like "oh, that happens sometimes when you don't use opengl" and now I'm feeling a pinch autogaslit by my ai coding companion. why is the text not fonting?

You misunderstand what an AI can do and what it cannot do

463035818_is_not_an_ai
oh I can.
I made a program to test graphics. I think I'm running a test program with lorem ipsum built in. and I think I loaded my font. but I don't see my font, I see rectangles.

I'm doing what you asked, lets not talk about ai. it exists. but we should stay on topic.
463035818_is_not_an_ai
I was expecting an output that I did not recieve, and since the ai is a part of my toolkit, it bears no mention. you're right

anyways, give me a second to compile. I have backgups in my git. but I mighta made changes so let me check that the screenshot even is the right version

sanity check complete, I need to go to an earlier version, one of my updates botched it. meaning, the code is newer than the screenshot and we wont debug it if I don't use the right code. hold on

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

the blocks look the right size for each letter, my guess would be that there's an alpha blending issue

hey Alan, that's a good thought, I'm trying to move this to chat so the website doesn't yell at me, I'm tired of making admins mad today with my lack of neticate, here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/258028/discussion-between-user179283-and-463035818-is-not-an-ai
oh, but in chat, I said this: ''
okay so this code snippet // Show ImGui demo window
ImGui::ShowDemoWindow(); is supposed to produce a window that looks like this blog.conan.io/assets/… instead of what we actually got'' so we're on the same wave length, I also thought about surface transparency the other night, but... failed

Don't take coding advice from mindless chat bots with no real intelligence and definitely no idea what they are doing.

Step into the imgui sdl backend and play close attention to the blendMode field of all surfaces and textures involved. The software renderer is capable of doing alpha, so it's not that.

@Botje I asked you a question in chat. But tldr i'll ask it again since no one seems to use chat. For the back end, any particular files I should search first, and are there any known classes or objects that might need to be tweaked? And if so... ...is this a bug in SDL? Or?

If the demo does not work that is a bug. I think it is only a matter of setting the correct blend mode. The Imgui backend only has a single method that actually does the drawing so I would start there.

Any reason you aren't calling ImGui_ImplSDLRenderer2_NewFrame() (which looks like it's doing some font stuff) before ImGui_ImplSDL2_NewFrame() like the SDL2 example does?
